# Projectivization of a coherent sheaf using resolution by vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, coherent-sheaves

Let $\mathcal{F}\to X$ be a coherent sheaf over a compact Kahler manifold and let $E^{\bullet}\to \mathcal{F}$ be a resolution of $\mathcal{F}$ by holomorphic vector bundles.

Is there a way to construct the projective bundle associated to $\mathcal{F}$ (cf. https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01OA) using the resolution $E^{\bullet}$ and the standard projectivization of vector bundles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_bundle)?

Comment: What do you mean by "construct" here? The Wikipedia description is less formal, but I don't see a big difference other than The Stacks Project allowing for arbitrary quasicoherent sheaves (and possibly the dualizing issue). That said, I would expect to have more luck understanding this object in terms of vector bundles by looking at the flattening stratification (assuming this exists in the general Kahler case).

Comment: One can get a derived projectivization via resolutions: https://arxiv.org/abs/2202.11636

Comment: Given the exact sequence $E_1\to E_0\to\mathcal{F}\to 0$ where $E_1$ and $E_0$ are vector bundles, we see that $\mathrm{Proj}(\mathcal{F})$ is the subscheme of $\mathbb{P}_X(E_0)$ defined by the ideal generated by the image of $E_1$ in $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_X(E_0)}(1)$ via the inclusion of $E_1$ in $E_0$.